# get real date and time with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to retrieve the real date and time where the user is based using JQuery. Is this possible, I understand that using the `Date();` object the time is retrieved from the user's machine, which isn't safe because user's can't changes their system time settings. How can I retrieve the real date and time?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to sent the time from the server to the client script like in as an epoc value then use it to create a time object like `var date = new Date(1400493270815)` where the value `1400493270815` is from the server

Comment: If you can't trust the user's browser, you will have to rely on a date/time provided by your server (and apply time-zone if their location can be determined reliably).